# dataTable, inputText and value saving of a "not direct" bean variable

Tags: jsf-2

I have a dataTable with a list of inputTexts:

```
<h2>
    Attributes
</h2>
<h:dataTable
    value="#{detailModel.getAfterObjectAttributeSpecifications()}"
    var="specification"
    styleClass="waiFormTable" >
    <h:column>
        #{specification.name}:
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText id="attribute" value="#{detailModel.getAfterObjectAttribute(specification.name)}" disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}"/>  
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The value of the inputText is not a direct bean field (detailModel.getAfterObjectAttribute(specification.name)).
If I change the value and want it save, how should I do?

Thank you for any help
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It has to be a real property or at least a `Map` value. E.g.

```
<h:dataTable
    value="#{detailModel.afterObjectAttributeSpecifications}"
    var="specification"
    styleClass="waiFormTable" >
    <h:column>
        #{specification.name}:
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText id="attribute" value="#{detailModel.afterObjectAttributes[specification.name]}" disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}"/>  
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

with

```
public Map<String, String> getAfterObjectAttributes() {
    return afterObjectAttributes;
}
```